# Why are borrows not allowed in mutable function's argument

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

Title is probably a bit confusing, what I mean is that when I try to compile:

```
if folder_file_paths.len() > compressed_data.len() {
    compressed_data.reserve(folder_file_paths.len() - compressed_data.len() );
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `compressed_data` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src/ImageMatching/main.rs:33:59
   |
33 |         compressed_data.reserve(folder_file_paths.len() - compressed_data.len() );
   |         ---------------                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       - mutable borrow ends here
   |         |                                                 |
   |         mutable borrow occurs here                        immutable borrow occurs here
```

But I can't think of a reason why this is a problem, as shouldn't the argument be processed first, the resulting `usize` value be copied, and then the `reserve` function run?

When would the argument of a function be calculated *after* the actual function starts executing?

Edit: `folder_file_path` is a `Vec`, and `compressed_data` is a `HashMap`

Comment: Please can you include more information, such as the type of the objects. It looks like this is going to be because `compressed_data.reserve` takes a mutable self reference, but that isn't clear from the code you've provided.

Comment: @PeterHall Added the types, but my question is that when a function takes a mutable reference, why does that affect what the arguments are, since it should be executed first.

Comment: @HandofC'thuhlu as you didn't include [mcve], we can only guess, take a look at the feature NLL, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/7076153