# How to assign to the variable used in match expression inside a match branch?

Tags: rust, match, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement a general function `join()` that can work on any iterator of iterators. I have a problem with the borrow checker in a `match` expression inside the `next()` method implementation. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
pub struct Join<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: IntoIterator,
{
    outer_iter: I,
    inner_iter: Option<<I::Item as IntoIterator>::IntoIter>,
}

impl<I> Join<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: IntoIterator,
{
    pub fn new(mut iter: I) -> Join<I> {
        let inner_iter = iter.next().map(|it| it.into_iter());
        Join {
            outer_iter: iter,
            inner_iter,
        }
    }
}

impl<I> Iterator for Join<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: IntoIterator,
{
    type Item = <I::Item as IntoIterator>::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        loop {
            match &mut self.inner_iter {
                Some(ref mut it) => match it.next() {
                    Some(x) => {
                        return Some(x);
                    }
                    None => {
                        self.inner_iter = self.outer_iter.next().map(|it| it.into_iter());
                    }
                },
                None => {
                    return None;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pub trait MyItertools: Iterator {
    fn join(self) -> Join<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        Self::Item: IntoIterator,
    {
        Join::new(self)
    }
}

impl<I> MyItertools for I where I: Iterator {}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::MyItertools;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let input = [[1], [2]];
        let expected = [&1, &2];
        assert_eq!(input.iter().join().collect::<Vec<_>>(), expected);
    }
}
```

Text of error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.inner_iter` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:39:25
   |
33 |             match &mut self.inner_iter {
   |                        --------------- borrow of `self.inner_iter` occurs here
...
39 |                         self.inner_iter = self.outer_iter.next().map(|it| it.into_iter());
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `self.inner_iter` occurs here
```

I understand why the borrow checker complains about my code, but I did not find a good solution, only an ugly workaround:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    loop {
        match self.inner_iter.take() {
            Some(mut it) => {
                match it.next() {
                    Some(x) => { self.inner_iter = Some(it); return Some(x); }
                    None => { self.inner_iter = self.outer_iter.next().map(|it| it.into_iter()); }
                }
            }
            None => { return None; }
        }
    }
}
```

I imagine that situations like this occur regularly; how can I rewrite my code to deal with them or avoid them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler reproduction of the problem:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = (42, true);
    match a {
        (ref _i, true) => a = (99, false),
        (ref _i, false) => a = (42, true),
    }
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `a` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:4:27
  |
4 |         (ref _i, true) => a = (99, false),
  |          ------           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `a` occurs here
  |          |
  |          borrow of `a` occurs here

error[E0506]: cannot assign to `a` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:5:28
  |
5 |         (ref _i, false) => a = (42, true),
  |          ------            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `a` occurs here
  |          |
  |          borrow of `a` occurs here
```

This is a weakness of the AST-based borrow checker. When [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes) are enabled, this [works as-is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6019e70a7cea648868f9c3af47691689&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015). The enhanced MIR-based borrow checker can see that there's no borrow of the matched-on variable at the point at which you try to replace it.

---

For what it's worth, your `join` is just a [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```
input.iter().flat_map(|x| x)
```

Or a [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten):

```
input.iter().flatten()
```

You can see how these [implement `next`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.26.2/src/libcore/iter/mod.rs#L2634-L2644) for another idea:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    loop {
        if let Some(v) = self.inner_iter.as_mut().and_then(|i| i.next()) {
            return Some(v);
        }
        match self.outer_iter.next() {
            Some(x) => self.inner_iter = Some(x.into_iter()),
            None => return None,
        }
    }
}
```

This clearly delineates that the iterator value doesn't *really* borrow from `inner_iter`.

---

Without looking at `flatten`, I would have chosen to clearly indicate that there's no overlapping borrowing by [taking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) the `Option` and restoring it if it is `Some`, as you've done:

```
match self.inner_iter.take() {
    Some(mut it) => match it.next() {
        Some(x) => {
            self.inner_iter = Some(it);
            return Some(x);
        }
        None => {
            self.inner_iter = self.outer_iter.next().map(|it| it.into_iter());
        }
    },
    None => {
        return None;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In these kind of situations, I find useful to write the code in two pieces: first collect the data, then update the mutable:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    loop {
        //collect the change into a local variable
        let ii = match &mut self.inner_iter {
            Some(ref mut it) => {
                match it.next() {
                    Some(x) => { return Some(x); }
                    None => self.outer_iter.next().map(|it| it.into_iter())
                }
            }
            None => { return None; }
        };
        //self.inner_iter is no longer borrowed, update
        self.inner_iter = ii;
    }
}
```

The fact that all the branches that do not modify the `inner_iter` do a `return` makes the code easier.

Comment: You could also do: `self.inner_iter = match &mut self.inner_iter {...};`. Pulling the assignment out of the match expression is what satisfies the borrow checker here. Whether to use a local variable or not merely concerns readability in this case.