# Why can the Rust compiler break borrowing rules when using Rust 1.31?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I am studying *Rust by Example* and running code from [the "Alias" page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow/alias.html):

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    z: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut point = Point { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };

    {
        let borrowed_point = &point;
        let another_borrow = &point;

        // Data can be accessed via the references and the original owner
        println!(
            "Point has coordinates: ({}, {}, {})",
            borrowed_point.x, another_borrow.y, point.z
        );

        // Error! Can't borrow point as mutable because it's currently
        // borrowed as immutable.
        let mutable_borrow = &mut point;
        println!(
            "Point has coordinates: ({}, {}, {})",
            mutable_borrow.x, mutable_borrow.y, mutable_borrow.z
        );

        let mutable_borrow2 = &mut point;
        println!(
            "Point has coordinates: ({}, {}, {})",
            mutable_borrow2.x, mutable_borrow2.y, mutable_borrow2.z
        );

        // TODO ^ Try uncommenting this line

        // Immutable references go out of scope
    }

    {
        let mutable_borrow = &mut point;

        // Change data via mutable reference
        mutable_borrow.x = 5;
        mutable_borrow.y = 2;
        mutable_borrow.z = 1;

        // Error! Can't borrow `point` as immutable because it's currently
        // borrowed as mutable.
        //let y = &point.y;
        // TODO ^ Try uncommenting this line

        // Error! Can't print because `println!` takes an immutable reference.
        //println!("Point Z coordinate is {}", point.z);
        // TODO ^ Try uncommenting this line

        // Ok! Mutable references can be passed as immutable to `println!`
        println!(
            "Point has coordinates: ({}, {}, {})",
            mutable_borrow.x, mutable_borrow.y, mutable_borrow.z
        );

        // Mutable reference goes out of scope
    }

    // Immutable references to point are allowed again
    let borrowed_point = &point;
    println!(
        "Point now has coordinates: ({}, {}, {})",
        borrowed_point.x, borrowed_point.y, borrowed_point.z
    );
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=788a836e7f12d6e05a4d2e5c534e87db)

I do **not** get compilation errors when running this code on Windows with the latest nightly build of the Rust compiler (`rustc 1.31.0-nightly (f99911a4a 2018-10-23)`). The latest nightly build of the Rust compiler in the Rust Playground **does** provide the expected compilation errors.

Why is this? Why can the Rust compiler break borrowing rules? How can I fix this locally to get the expected errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create a new Cargo project with Rust 1.31, you automatically opt-into Rust edition 2018:

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"
```

This turns on [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423), which enables a smarter form of the borrow checker. If you want the old behavior, you can switch back to `2015`; this will cause your code to produce the expected errors. I would encourage you to continue using the 2018 edition, however.

The Rust Playground offers switching between editions:

[image: playground edition switch]

The Playground currently defaults to edition 2015, and after Rust 1.31 is stabilized, the Playground will change its default to edition 2018.

> How I can change this example to provide expected behavior

You **cannot** in Rust 2018. Before non-lexical lifetimes, the Rust compiler was simply insufficiently intelligent. The code itself *is safe*, but the compiler could not see that. The compiler is now that smart, so the code compiles. There is no reason to have a compiler mode to make intrinsically correct code fail to compile.

You should file an issue with *Rust by Example*, letting them know that their example is no longer valid in Rust 2018.

Comment: It would be nice to make changes to the project ["Rust by examples"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/) and the "book" may be too to update code installations of so smart (cool) behavior of the compiler.

Comment: @AnatoliiKosorukov: Indeed, I expect that as 1.31 ships a whole lot of documentation will need updating. It would be a bit premature to do so before it ships, though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. all of the official documentation (including RBE), is versioned with the releases ([for example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rust-by-example/)), but the nightly isn't updated either. That means that RBE will be out of date for multiple months :-(

Answer (score 5):

The solution is in the prelude of the code.

> Data can be immutably borrowed any number of times, but while immutably borrowed, the original data can't be mutably borrowed. On the other hand, only one mutable borrow is allowed at a time. The original data can be borrowed again only after the mutable reference goes out of scope.

Which means, you can borrow a value as often as you like, but only have one mutable borrow at a time (in a scope).

You may be wondering, why the code compile with [`#![feature(nll)]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e3d676a388430f1f127d2bba11dd7019).

The reason is that 'nll' (non-lexical-lifetimes) allows the compiler to create lifetimes for borrows beyond the scope of scopes (everything between `{` and `}`). It will now see, that after the use of the borrowed value for printing it won't be used anymore, so the lifetime of that borrow ends right after the `println!`.

This won't break any rules as stated above. You can't have more than mutable borrow at the same time, e.g.

```
let mut point = Point { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };

let p1 = &mut point;
let p2 = &point;

println!("Point has coordinates: ({}, {})", p1.x, p2.y);
```

won't work! Keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes. It is. I do not understand one thing - in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=2b48b546e99b20c2ac62a3d4cf53cc9b) the compiler work as expected - do not compile this code. In another place, the compiler works differently (all code is compiled).

Comment: @hellow — in case you didn't know, we have [a SO chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) you are welcome to join! (Feel free to flag this comment as no longer needed)

Answer (score 3):

This is so-called *non-lexical lifetimes* - a feature currently coming into language and not available in 2015 version. In short, with them the reference is dropped once it is not used anymore, and not at the end of scope, as before (and as it is stated in docs). You can check this by using `borrowed_point` after `mutable_borrow` - this should trigger the error even with NLL.

Comment: Ok. Please, provide a short example (illustrated this (correct) behavior).

Comment: *"not available in 2015 version"* Not correct, you can opt-in in that unstable feature via `#![feature(nll)]`

Comment: How I can change this example to provide expected behavior - "multiple immutable borrowing, one mutable borrowing"? Please, proved an example to clarify your suggestion.

Comment: After adding `#![feature(nll)]` to the first line of the source file (!) it is compiled too.