# How to limit the scope in which a value is borrowed in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I’m trying to do some memoization in Rust and I’m running afoul of the borrow checker.

```
fn calc_deps(cache: &mut HashMap<String, String>, key: &String) -> String {
    if let Some(v) = cache.get(key) {
        v
    } else {
        let r = /* computations */
        cache.insert(key.clone(),r.clone());
        r
    }
}
```

I’m told that cache is borrowed twice. Why is it a problem if I’m done with get by the time I get to insert? Is there a way for me to encode that information?

Comment: If I [make edits to your code so that I get the borrowing error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7afd32c77449323f34ca70007af64837), it compiles on nightly with `#![feature(nll)]`. See [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes)

Comment: Also tangentially relevant: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the lifetime of `v` is for the whole `if/else` block, even though it is not available in the `else` section. You can get around this by with the help of `Option::cloned`.

```
pub fn calc_deps(cache: &mut HashMap<String, String>, key: &String) -> String {
    if let Some(v) = cache.get(key).cloned() {
        v
    } else {
        let r = String::from("computations");
        cache.insert(key.clone(), r.clone());
        r
    }
}
```

`Option::cloned` maps `Option<&T>` to `Option<T>` by cloning the contents. So now `v` becomes `String` instead of `&String`, and is no longer borrowing `cache`.

Another option is to use the `HashMap::entry/or_insert_with` interface. It's probably more idiomatic, but it requires unconditionally cloning the `key`.

```
pub fn calc_deps(cache: &mut HashMap<String, String>, key: String) -> String {
    cache
        .entry(key)
        .or_insert_with(|| String::from("computations"))
        .clone()
}
```

You could also simply use `or_insert` instead of `or_insert_with`, but that would require doing your computations for `r` unconditionally.

```
pub fn calc_deps(cache: &mut HashMap<String, String>, key: String) -> String {
    cache
        .entry(key)
        .or_insert(String::from("computations"))
        .clone()
}
```

Comment: I like these solutions. What if I wanted to stick to the initial idea to basically implement the functions you showed us here? Shouldn't I be able to write something like: 
```
{ let x;
  { x = cache.get(key).clone() };
  if let Some(v) = x { ... ```
Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @simon1505475: Because when you clone an `Option<&String>`, you still have an `Option<&String>`. That's why I used `map` to take the reference out, and then I cloned it, because calling `clone` on a reference clones the referred object. However, I just learned about another function for `Option` that does what I did with `map`. `if let Some(v) = cache.get(key).cloned() { ...`. (not that it's `cloned` instead of `clone`) I'll be updating my answer to reflect it.