# Why is add_cart complaining with an error?

Tags: rust

Trying to understand why `merchant.add_cart()` is complaining and `merchant.add_product()` is fine. Both `Cart` and `Product` contain more or less the same structure

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Merchant<'a> {
    id: u64,
    name: String,
    products: HashMap<u64, &'a Product>,
    carts: HashMap<u64, &'a Cart>,
}

impl<'a> Merchant<'a> {
    pub fn new(id: u64, name: String) -> Merchant<'a> {
        Merchant {
            id,
            name,
            products: HashMap::new(),
            carts: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_product(&mut self, product: &'a Product) {
        self.products.insert(product.id, product);
    }

    pub fn add_cart(&mut self, cart: &'a Cart) {
        self.carts.insert(cart.id, cart);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Product {
    id: u64,
    name: String,
    amount_in_cents: u64,
}

impl Product {
    pub fn new(id: u64, name: String, amount_in_cents: u64) -> Product {
        Product {
            id,
            name,
            amount_in_cents,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Cart {
    id: u64,
}

impl Cart {
    pub fn new(id: u64) -> Cart {
        Cart { id }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let apple = Product::new(1, String::from("Apple"), 10000);
    let orange = Product::new(2, String::from("Orange"), 20000);
    let guava = Product::new(3, String::from("Guava"), 30000);

    let mut merchant = Merchant::new(1, String::from("Oak Market"));

    merchant.add_product(&apple);
    merchant.add_product(&orange);
    merchant.add_product(&guava);

    let cart = Cart::new(1);
    merchant.add_cart(&cart);
}
```

`merchant.add_cart(&cart);` is complaining with

```
cart does not live long enough: borrowed value does not live long enough
```

Using `rustc 1.31.0`

Comment: Your code compiles on 1.31.0 - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=f32696019328725e145e21d59775c4d6

Comment: That is strange. I am using 1.31.0 and I still see the error

Comment: @ĐorđeZeljić: Only with 2018 edition enabled.

Comment: @ChristianFazzini yes, thank you. btw NLL is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I compile your code, the full error message is this:

```
   |
70 |     merchant.add_cart(&cart);
   |                        ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
71 | }
   | - `cart` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

That last line is telling you your problem. You declared `apple`, `orange` and `guava` before `merchant`, so they outlive `merchant`, and so it is okay to store references to them. However, you declare `cart` after `merchant`, so `merchant` outlives it, thus you are not able to store a reference to it.

Note that your code will compile in Rust 2018 edition, because of non-lexical-lifetimes, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes).