# Why am I allowed to do a mutable borrow of variable more than once?

Tags: rust

I was just reading about `mut` and how it differs from `&mut`, and when you want to use the two.
So I was going through [this article](https://cotigao.medium.com/mutable-reference-in-rust-995320366e22).

The article has this code snippet, where two mutable references are made to the same variable:

```
fn main() {
   let mut i:i32 = 1;
   let ref_i = &mut i;
   let another_ref_i = &mut i;
}
```

According to the article, this should fail, because two active mutable references are not allowed, so it should fail with this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `i` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:4:29
  |
3 |    let ref_i = &mut i;
  |                     - first mutable borrow occurs here
4 |    let another_ref_i = &mut i;
  |                             ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
5 | }
  | - first borrow ends here
```

But this does not happen for me. For me it compiles fine.

I then looked in the [rust handbook](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/references-and-borrowing.html), for a similar example, and found this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    let y = &mut x;

    *y += 1;

    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Which should fail with the same error. But does'nt.

This confuses me I thought that a mutable reference would disallow the borrowed value to be used for the rest of the code.

Can someone help me with what it happening?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055461/why-can-we-have-multiple-mutable-references-to-the-same-data-in-the-same-scope.

Comment: In principle, those code segments should fail. But Rust is pretty clever nowadays when it comes to dropping values that aren't used. Basically, when you do a second mutable borrow, if Rust can prove that the first one is never used again, it will just quietly drop the first one rather than complaining about it.

Comment: Rust inserts a `drop(y)` after the last use of `y`, which allows your code to work. This interpretation doesn't affect Rust's guarantees, and makes many valid patterns compile that previously failed. As others pointed out, look up non-lexical lifetimes for details.

Comment: Nitpick: Rust doesn't "insert a `drop(y)`." That's unnecessary. (If it did, NLL wouldn't work without std.) The compiler is capable of realizing NLL itself, without calling std functions.

Comment: @cdhowie `drop` is part of `core` so it works without std…

Comment: @Jmb Regardless, `drop()` is a mechanism for _us_ that explicitly destroys a value. The compiler is able to realize NLL without emitting additional function calls.

Comment: @cdhowie, if you really want to nitpick, the compiler doesn't emit any function calls for `drop(y)` either: `drop` gets inlined and since its body is empty it disappears. Regardless of what the compiler really does behind the scene, saying that it (behaves as if it) inserts `drop` is a great way to explain what happens without getting lost in irrelevant details.