# How to take the first element of a BTreeSet without clone

Tags: rust, set

I need to implement a function similar to the unstable [`BTreeSet::pop_first()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.pop_first).

It is not a duplicate of [Getting first member of a BTreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507150/getting-first-member-of-a-btreeset), since I ask for a way get the first element of a BTreeSet **without making a copy**.

```
fn pop<O:Ord>(set: &mut std::collections::BTreeSet<O>) -> O
```

Based on a previous question ([Getting first member of a BTreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507150/getting-first-member-of-a-btreeset)), I get a compiler error about a mutable use after an inmutable one:

```
pub fn pop<O:Ord>(set: &mut std::collections::BTreeSet<O>) -> O {

    let n = {
        let mut start_iter = set.iter();
        start_iter.next().unwrap()
    };

    set.take(n).unwrap()
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*set` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> src/main.rs:493:5
    |
489 |         let mut start_iter = set.iter();
    |                              --- immutable borrow occurs here
...
493 |     set.take(n).unwrap()
    |     ^^^^----^^^
    |     |   |
    |     |   immutable borrow later used by call
    |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

If I replace `set.iter()` with `set.iter().clone()` the code works, but I would like to not make copies of the elements of the set because it will be a costly operation.

How can I implement such a `pop` function?

rustc version `1.41.0`

Comment: The elements of the iterator are borrowed from the set, so `n` is borrowed from the set as well. Have you considered using a `BinaryHeap` as suggested in the linked question?

Comment: I need an ordered data type that removes duplicates. It seems a `BinaryHeap` can not remove duplicates.

Comment: I don't agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster. The linked question doesn't solve my problem: I what to remove the first element and get it *without* a copy, like `pop_first` seems to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to implement that function like you ask without access to the internals of `BTreeSet`: The elements of the iterator are borrowed from the set, so n is borrowed from the set as well. While you have borrowed something from the set, you cannot modify it.

You could:

- Use `clone()`/`cloned()`, like you mentioned. If you were worried it would clone all elements in the iterator when calling `pop_first()`, that's not the case. It would clone only the one element since iterators are lazy.
- Keep both a `BinaryHeap` and a `HashSet` of your elements. Before inserting an element into the `BinaryHeap`, check whether it is already in the `HashSet`.
- Find/implement an extended `BTreeSet` from scratch that has this functionality.

Comment: Your options are valid, but finally I'm using an element with Rc-RefCell. This way I don't need to copy the whole data, only the smartpointer.