# Why does the borrow checker disallow a second mutable borrow even if the first one is already out of scope?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

### Background

I know that the borrow checker disallows more than one mutable borrows. For example, the code below is invalid:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 42;
    let a = &mut x;
    let b = &mut x;
    println!("{} {}", a, b);
}
```

However, if the first borrow is dropped due to out of scope, the second borrow is valid:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;
    {
        let a = &mut x;
        println!("{}", a);
    }
    let b = &mut x;
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

Because of [non-lexical lifetimes (NLL)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/1403530), the first borrow doesn't even have to be out of scope — the borrow checker only requires it not to be used anymore. So, the code below is valid in Rust 2018:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;

    let a = &mut x;
    println!("{}", a);

    let b = &mut x;
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

---

### The Problem

But I don't understand why the code below is invalid:

```
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let s = "ab".to_owned();
    let mut char_iter = s.chars();

    let mut i = next(&mut char_iter);
    dbg!(i.next());

    let mut j = next(&mut char_iter);
    dbg!(j.next());
}

fn next<'a>(char_iter: &'a mut Chars<'a>) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + 'a {
    char_iter.take_while(|&ch| ch != ' ')
}
```

Compile error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `char_iter` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:10:22
   |
7  |     let mut i = next(&mut char_iter);
   |                      -------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |     let mut j = next(&mut char_iter);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
11 |     dbg!(j.next());
12 | }
   | - first borrow might be used here, when `i` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl std::iter::Iterator`
```

From the error message I thought that maybe NLL doesn't support this case yet. So, I dropped `i` early:

```
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let s = "ab".to_owned();
    let mut char_iter = s.chars();

    {
        let mut i = next(&mut char_iter);
        dbg!(i.next());
    }

    let mut j = next(&mut char_iter);
    dbg!(j.next());
}

fn next<'a>(char_iter: &'a mut Chars<'a>) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + 'a {
    char_iter.take_while(|&ch| ch != ' ')
}
```

([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6f975e02955ae9b1c4582402c548267))

But I got a more confusing error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `char_iter` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:12:22
   |
8  |         let mut i = next(&mut char_iter);
   |                          -------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
12 |     let mut j = next(&mut char_iter);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                      first borrow later used here
```

Why does it say `first borrow later used here` even if `i` is already dropped and out of scope before?

---

### An Alternative Approach

The code is compiled if I change the signature of `next` function into this:

```
fn next(char_iter: impl Iterator<Item = char>) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> {
    char_iter.take_while(|&ch| ch != ' ')
}
```

But still, I want to understand why the original `next` function doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's decipher this type deduction magic here. `impl Iterator` is actually a concrete type: `Chars` that wrapped with `TakeWhile`, so you may rewrite your method like this (btw, an interesting task is to determine the `&char`'s lifetime):

```rust
fn next<'a>(
    char_iter: &'a mut Chars<'a>,
) -> TakeWhile<&'a mut Chars<'a>, impl FnMut(&char) -> bool> {
    char_iter.take_while(|&ch| ch != ' ')
}
```

Now you may see that the output type lives as long as the input and vice versa. That lifetime, in fact, derived from the `&str` that is originally used. Therefore, you may conclude that the resulted type lives as long as the used string (i.e. to the end of the `main`) and even explicit `drop(i)` won't help you, because compiler knows that the `Chars` is borrowed till the end. For working nll you must (unfortunately?) help the compiler:

```rust
fn next<'a, 'b: 'a>(
    char_iter: &'a mut Chars<'b>,
) -> TakeWhile<&'a mut Chars<'b>, impl FnMut(&char) -> bool> {
    char_iter.take_while(|&ch| ch != ' ')
}
```

Comment: Nice to know that `impl` trait can be used in type parameters. I previously thought it can only be used in argument or return types as per [the official doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html#using-impl-trait-in-more-places).

Comment: I didn't know it either, I thought to give that example as a rough equivalent but it compiles to my surprise.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're explicitly telling the borrow checker that `i` lives as long as `char_iter` in the following block by declaring both to have the same lifetime `'a`.

```rust
fn next<'a>(char_iter: &'a mut Chars<'a>) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + 'a {
    char_iter.take_while(|&ch| ch != ' ')
}
```

This means that the compiler believes that `&mut char_iter` is still in use as long as `char_iter` is still in scope. That is, until the end of `main()`.

Comment: I think the real question is “Why does reducing the scope of `i` not work?"?