# Can mutable and immutable reference exist at the same time?

Tags: rust

Consider:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x: i32 = 5;
    let y = &mut x;
    let z: &i32 = y;
    println!("{}", *z);
    //*y = 5;
    println!("{}", *y);
    println!("{}", *z);
}
```

Without commenting out line 6 the code compiles.

It seems to me that both the reference `y` and `z` are in scope from line 5 to 7.
It sure only *reads* from `y`, but I've always been told that mutable and immutable reference can not *exist* at the same time. In fact, it results in a compile error if I replace line 4 with `let z: &i32 = &x`.

What is going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes)

Comment: @L.F. I don't think this is caused by non-lexical lifetimes. Because `z` is being used line 8, it won't be invalidated by then. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're right! I retracted my close vote. It seems that the reborrowing somehow downgrades `y` to a non-mutable reference in terms of usage, even though its type is still `&mut i32`. I'm really not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable references do not expect the underlying value to change and this is problematic if we do have a mutable reference. You can however have multiple immutable references because underlying data is not gonna change.

- Scope of reference starts when it is first introduced and ends when it is used for the last time. That means we can add a third mutable reference underneath the println statement

```rs
    fn main() {
        let mut x: i32 = 5;
        // scope of y starts here
        // we can have multiple immutable references so I moved "mut"
        let y = &x;
        // scope of z starts here
        let z: &i32 = y;
        // scope of z ends here
        println!("{}", *z);
        //*y = 5;
        // scope of y ends here
        println!("{}", *y);
    
        // this should work
        let a = &mut x;
    }
```