# cannot borrow <var> as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable immutable borrow occurs here

Tags: rust

Learning some rust programming (Leetcode Q3).

Got the error:

```
cannot borrow `result` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
immutable borrow occurs hererustcE0502
solution.rs(42, 23): mutable borrow occurs here
solution.rs(44, 13): mutable borrow later used here
```

I can change the program from `if result.is_none() {` to `if current.is_none() {` and it'll work.  But current and result are not the same thing.  current is the last node in a linked list and result is head.  How do I do this?

Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=741c07fad8aa730a44ba5773395aed7c

```
// Definition for singly-linked list.
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

impl ListNode {
  #[inline]
  fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    ListNode {
      next: None,
      val
    }
  }
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Solution;

#[allow(dead_code)]
impl Solution {
    pub fn add_two_numbers(l1: Option<Box<ListNode>>, l2: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        let mut carry = 0;
        let mut result: Option<Box<ListNode>> = None;
        let mut current: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>> = &mut None;
        let mut node1 = &l1;
        let mut node2 = &l2;

        while node1.is_some() || node2.is_some() || carry > 0 {
          if node1.is_some() {
            carry += node1.as_ref().unwrap().val;
            node1 = &node1.as_ref().unwrap().next;
          }
          if node2.is_some() {
            carry += node2.as_ref().unwrap().val;
            node2 = &node2.as_ref().unwrap().next;
          }

          if result.is_none() { // solution.rs(42, 23): mutable borrow occurs here
            result = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(carry % 10)));
            current = &mut result; // solution.rs(44, 13): mutable borrow later used here
          } else {
            current.as_mut().unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(carry % 10)));
            current = &mut current.as_mut().unwrap().next;
          }
          carry = carry / 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        fn from_vec(l: Vec<i32>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
          let mut start = None;
          let mut current: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>> = &mut None;
          for x in l {
            if current.is_none() {
              start = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(x)));
              current = &mut start;
            } else {
              current.as_mut().unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(x)));
              current = &mut current.as_mut().unwrap().next;
            }
          }
          return start;
        }
        fn compute(l1: Vec<i32>, l2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
          let result = Solution::add_two_numbers(from_vec(l1), from_vec(l2));
          let mut node = &result;
          let mut result_vec = Vec::new();
          while node.is_some() {
            result_vec.push(node.as_ref().unwrap().val);
            node = &node.as_ref().unwrap().next;
          }
          return result_vec;
        }
        assert_eq!(compute(vec![2, 4, 3], vec![5, 6, 4]), vec![7, 0, 8]);
        assert_eq!(compute(vec![0], vec![0]), vec![0]);
        assert_eq!(compute(vec![9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9], vec![9, 9, 9, 9]), vec![8, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside you should definitely read https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked lists are notoriously hard to implement in Rust because of these kinds of aliasing problems. The fundamental problem is that you can't take a mutable reference to something owned by `result` (even indirectly) and then use `result` again while that reference is alive.

The crux of the problem is that you check if `result` has a value -- in other words, whether the result list is empty or not.  This doesn't work because on the second iteration through the loop, `current` references `result` and so `result` is inaccessible as it's become exclusively borrowed.

The simplest way to fix this issue is to make the check of `result.is_some()` unnecessary by changing where `current` points.

Instead of having a reference to the last node in the list, which may or may not exist yet, have a reference to the *next node to be populated* -- that is, the `None` at the end -- which *always* exists *somewhere.*

```
let mut result: Option<Box<ListNode>> = None;
let mut current: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>> = &mut result;
```

Now you don't need to check `result` because `current` *always* points to where you should put the next node.  That could be in `result` or in a node's `next` field, but you don't have to care about that.

You can replace the `if`/`else` blocks with this:

```
*current = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(carry % 10)));
current = &mut current.as_mut().unwrap().next;
```

This works because you do not access `result` between its declaration and the moment you return it from the function.  When you return it, the `current` reference is no longer considered active because of [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/501250).

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9bdaa23c671afc5ae9766ed853156bd))

Comment: I was all but giving up on Rust yesterday.  Had to take some time to understand your approach but finally got it!  Now I could at least try a few more problems, thanks!