# Confusion around lifetimes and struct definitions

Tags: rust

(I am having trouble grasping lifetimes and ownership in Rust)

Consider the following Rust `struct` definition:

```
struct MyType<'lifetime> {
    one: &'lifetime u32,
    two: &'lifetime u32
}
```

My current interpretation of the above definition is as follows:

> I have defined a `struct MyType`. **The `<'lifetime>` next to its
> identifier refers to a specific lifetime of any one instance of
> `MyType`**. The fields `one` and `two` are references to `u32`s, and because they are annotated with `'lifetime`, **the integers that they refer to are guaranteed to live at least as long as the instance of the struct they belong to**.

To challenge my current understanding I created this example:

```
fn main() {

    let num1: u32 = 11;

    let instance: MyType;

    { // nested scope
        let num2: u32 = 22;
        instance = MyType {
            one: &num1,
            two: &num2
        };

        println!("{:?}", instance);
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs (printing `MyType { one: 11, two: 22 }`), but it seems to disprove my understanding:

As `instance` gets dropped at the end of `main`<sup>1</sup> and `num2` gets dropped at the end of the nested scope right before it, my initial understanding seems false: the integer referred to by the `two` field didn't live "at least as long as the struct instance".

Where am I wrong? What does the `'lifetime` in `struct MyType<'lifetime'>` actually refer to?

---

1: I am also unsure if this is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `instance` gets dropped at the end of `main`

With the code you've written, this is incorrect.  You've discovered [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/501250) (NLL).

In Rust, a value is only guaranteed to live until the end of its enclosing block if it implements the `Drop` trait.  Otherwise, the compiler is free to end its lifetime when it is no longer used.  Since you do not use `instance` after `num2` goes out of scope, this code is acceptable; the lifetime of `instance` is cut short after its last usage in the `println!()` call, at which point `num2` still exists.

There's a few ways you can make this code fail.

One is to move the `println!()` call outside of the anonymous block:

```
fn main() {
    let num1: u32 = 11;

    let instance: MyType;

    { // nested scope
        let num2: u32 = 22;
        instance = MyType {
            one: &num1,
            two: &num2
        };
    }

    // error[E0597]: `num2` does not live long enough
    println!("{:?}", instance);
}
```

The other is to implement `Drop` on `MyType`, which disables NLL for values of that type.

```
impl Drop for MyType<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) { }
}
```

This will produce:

```
error[E0597]: `num2` does not live long enough
...
borrow might be used here, when `instance` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `MyType`
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial understanding (documented in the quote block in the question) of what `<'lifetime>` represents in the `struct MyType<'lifetime>` definition is **wrong**.

`<'lifetime>` in the definition of the struct represents a generic type parameter, denoting that `MyType` contains a reference that borrows something with the `'lifetime` lifetime - it *does not* represent the lifetime of any given instance of the `MyType` struct.

Comment: True, but unrelated to what you're seeing in this question, since the referent integers still have to outlive the struct instance.