# When does a reference go out of scope?

Tags: rust

Why do I borrow twice in this example?

```
fn main() {
    let mut my_string = String::from("this is a string");
    let mut other_string_ref = &mut my_string; // first mutable reference 
    mut_ref(&mut my_string); 
    mut_ref(&mut other_string_ref); // invalid, because borrowed twice
}

// borrow happens when this function is called
fn mut_ref(s: &mut String) {
    print!("{}\n", s)
}
```

I know that you can only borrow once to avoid memory races. I also know that a variable goes out of scope when it is no longer used. Why does `my_string` not go out of scope after `mut_ref(&mut my_string);`. It is not used afterwards. We only use `other_string_ref`

Comment: "borrow happens when this function is called" - a bit incorrect. The value is borrowed when you prepare arguments for a call. The function is not yet called at that moment.

Comment: "Why does my_string not go out of scope" - it can't, because it's currently borrowed.

Comment: Here's a version of your code without some unnecessary decorations: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3069a5ad26f7b2230d183a7e3464e93f hopefully in it, you can see better why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your  `// invalid because borrowed twice` comment is on the wrong line. It is the previous line where you try and borrow `my_string` again that causes the problem.

`let mut other_string_ref = &mut my_string;` creates a mutable (exclusive) reference to `my_string`. When you try and call `mut_ref` the first time you, you try and create a second mutable reference. This is not allowed as `other_string_ref` is still in scope.

`my_string` can't go out of scope because it is still referenced by `other_string_ref`.

See also:

- [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/7076153)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is you (try to) have two mutable references and they are overlapping (active at the same time). This is not allowed. However, if you rewrite your code in a way so one of the references is fully processed before the other, it will work.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut my_string = String::from("this is a string");
    mut_ref(&mut my_string); 
    
    let other_string_ref = &mut my_string;  
    mut_ref(other_string_ref);
}


fn mut_ref(s: &mut String) {
    print!("{}\n", s)
}
```