# Correct definition of lifetime of a reference in Rust

Tags: rust, scope, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a doubt about the definition of *lifetime of a reference* in Rust:

the two definitions I've found in most articles are the following two:

1. "The lifetime of a reference is the set of lines of code in which the reference **is valid**".
2. "The lifetime of a reference is the set of lines of code in which the reference **needs to exist**"

Now, here's my confusion. Suppose having the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let n = 5;
    let p = &n;               //+----------+------------+
                              //           |            |
    // do stuff...            //           | 'a         |
                              //           |            |
    println!("{}", p);        //+----------+            | 
                              //                        | 'b 
    // do something else      //                        |
    // without using p        //                        |
    // anymore...             //                        |
}                             //+-----------------------+
```

Then:

- according to definition (1), `'b` seems to be the correct lifetime, since `n`, the referenced variable continues to exist until it goes out of scope, so the reference **is valid** until the closing `}`;
- according to definition (2), `'a` seems to be the correct answer, since `p` is **only used** until call to `println!()`, so it only **needs to live** until there.

Then, which definition (if any of them) is the correct one?

Personally, I've thought that def. (2) could take to some problems:

In fact, if `p` were passed as input to a function having signature:

```
fn foo<'x> (p: &'x i32) -> &'x i32
```

then the output result, in that case would have the same lifetime as `p`, i.e. `'a`, making the result reference unusable after `p` is not used anymore.

Comment: Both, in a sense. See [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes)

Comment: In your `foo` example any usage of the returned value also counts as a use of the original reference so that's a non-issue.

Comment: Thanks @cafce25, however I still don't understand why would the returned value count as a use of the original reference? and, furthermore, which specific concrete lifetime, in that case, would be substituted to the generic lifetime parameter when the function is called?

Comment: It count's as such because you tell the compiler to treat it as such by specifying the same lifetime parameter on both `p` and the return type.