# Why should &mut buf[0..buf.len()] trigger a mutable/immutable borrow error?

Tags: rust

The following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af819c1f02ffa4fdf43002b942391b7f) triggers the well-described *cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable* error:

```rust
    let mut buf = [0; 128];
    let p = &mut buf[0..buf.len()];
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `buf` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:3:25
  |
3 |     let p = &mut buf[0..buf.len()];
  |                  -------^^^-------
  |                  |  |   |
  |                  |  |   immutable borrow occurs here
  |                  |  mutable borrow later used here
  |                  mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand the mechanism by which this error is produced, but isn't the compiler looking at this the wrong way around?

The range must be resolved prior to taking the mutable borrow of the array. Hence, it must have taken the immutable borrow, run `len()`, retrieved the length and released the immutable borrow to create the range before the mutable borrow can take place.

It doesn't make sense to take the mutable borrow before the range is known.

Is this an implementation limitation of lifetimes (e.g. similar to the problem that [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes) eventually solved), or is this on purpose?

Comment: Are you trying to borrow the whole thing, or is the intent to borrow a mutable slice? Maybe you need [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To supplement the other answer, consider that slicing an array is not actually a built-in operation, but is sugar for a call to [`IndexMut::index_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html#tymethod.index_mut) (in this case, or `Index::index` when slicing immutably).  Desugared, this line is equivalent to:

```
let p = &mut *IndexMut::index_mut(&mut buf, 0..buf.len());
```

This makes it more clear why the code is rejected. Arguments are always evaluated left-to-right, so `&mut buf` gets evaluated first, exclusively borrowing `buf` before `buf.len()` is evaluated.

However, the unbounded range `..` will be clamped to the bounds of the slice when indexing, so you could simply write:

```
let p = &mut buf[..];
```

This is by far the simplest way to fix the error.

Comment: The desugaring argument is the only one that makes sense to me, but still only seems to be a compiler limitation. The obvious way to generalize it is to resolve literals, then, immutable borrows, then mutable borrows. So I think I''ll chalk this up to a compiler limitation instead of a necessity.

Comment: @Anopt In simple cases this can work, but having a strict happens-before relationship between function arguments makes it easier for the programmer to reason about the program they are writing. In particular, when evaluating arguments would have side-effects, whether one has a mutable borrow influencing the order in which they evaluate would be a fantastic footgun. Being able to look at code and know what's going to happen in what order is significantly more important, IMO, than being able to express certain borrowing patterns succinctly.

Answer (score 1):

In the technical sense, yes, the immutable borrow to compute the length must complete before the mutable borrow.  However, I believe the compiler works on the basis of [the control-flow graph as outlined in the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md), which, while less convenient in this case, is much easier to reason about and probably a bunch easier to compute.  In this case, you have one statement which is not branching (for example, it is not a `match` or `if` statement) and which contains one assignment, so it's considered one component.

I agree that in this case, it seems very straightforward which order the operations must occur in, but it does not need to be so in general (expressions and statements may be very complex) and due to optimizations, the actual way the compiler works with it or the way the generated code works do not need to reflect the way we intuitively reason about it, so having simpler, slightly less flexible rules can be much more understandable than more complex or heuristic-based rules.

For example, the compiler will never actually emit a call to `len` here because it knows that value is a constant based on the array size and thus the borrow is entirely a fiction, but taking advantage of that would be very hard for humans to understand.

In this particular case, you have options that will make this nicer.  One is just to take the size first:

```
    let mut buf = [0; 128];
    let len = buf.len();
    let p = &mut buf[0..len];
```

This is an easy, general purpose solution.  You can also, in more recent versions of Rust, specifically borrow the array as a `mut` slice:

```
    let mut buf = [0; 128];
    let p = buf.as_mut_slice();
```

Comment: The method call is obviously nice on the self-documenting sense, but I'm not seeing a reason to bother with the length if you want to use slice syntax. Surely `&mut buf[..]` for the full slice with implicitly determined bounds would be the simplest solution here?