# Why doesn't std::cell::Ref use a reference instead of NonNull?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, unsafe, refcell

The `std::cell::Ref` struct in Rust is defined as follows:

```rust
pub struct Ref<'b, T: ?Sized + 'b> {
    // NB: we use a pointer instead of `&'b T` to avoid `noalias` violations, because a
    // `Ref` argument doesn't hold immutability for its whole scope, only until it drops.
    // `NonNull` is also covariant over `T`, just like we would have with `&T`.
    value: NonNull<T>,
    borrow: BorrowRef<'b>,
}
```

The `// NB` comment (I assume Nota bene / Nasty Bug or something?) implies that the following definition would not work, because it would be a `noalias` violation (do they mean the LLVM attributes in the backend?):

```rust
pub struct Ref2<'b, T: ?Sized + 'b> {
    value: &'b T,
    borrow: BorrowRef<'b>,
}
```

I don't understand this point, as I was under the impression that the non lexical lifetime semantics were properly preserved in code generation. Otherwise the following simple example (which of course compiles) would also be illegal, right?:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    v: &'a i32,
}
fn foo(x: &mut i32) {
    let f = Foo { v: x };
    *x = 5; // value modified while the `noalias` f.v pointer is still in scope
}
```

Could somebody with more knowledge about the internals shed some light on this for me?
I fear that I am misunderstanding something critical here, leading to potential issues in my own unsafe code.

Comment: Your last example works because `f` is no longer in scope when you modify `x` thanks to [Non-Lexical Lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/5397009).

Comment: @Jmb: please re-read the paragraph right before that code example :).

Comment: Well, the whole point of `RefCell` is that the `RefCell` _is_ still in scope while you access the mutable reference returned by `borrow_mut`, so if the `RefCell` held a mutable reference at the same time, that would violate Rust's aliasing rules (never mind LLVM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non lexical lifetimes were never a property of code generation. They were purely a borrow checker property, and borrow checking never impacts code generation.

The example you provided is not illegal according to LLVM. The problem with `noalias` only manifests with function parameter, because only they get a `noalias` attribute (at least currently). So, the only way to write a problematic code without unsafe code will be:

```rust
fn foo(reference: &String, mut data: String) {
    // Do not use `reference` anymore here.
    
    // Write to data.
    data = String::new();
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = String::new();
    foo(&v, v);
}
```

Except it doesn't compile, because you're moving a borrowed `v`. So there was actually no way to trigger a miscompilation.

With `RefCell` however, we can do that:

```rust
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};

fn foo<'a>(reference: Ref<'a, i32>, data: &'a RefCell<i32>) {
    drop(reference);
    // Do not use `reference` anymore here.
    
    *data.borrow_mut() = 0;
}

fn main() {
    let v = RefCell::new(0);
    foo(v.borrow(), &v);
}
```

Which would be LLVM UB if `Ref` would use a reference.

Comment: I didn't think immutable references got `noalias`.

Comment: @kmdreko They do. `noalias` has double meaning: for mutable references it mean nobody will write through anything but this reference, and for shared references it also means nobody will write through any other reference, and since this reference is immutable it's a promise nobody will write at all.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this insight

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Just one point: I didn't say that NLLs were a property of code generation, but that their **semantics** would have to be preserved (respected / mirrored), by the assembly that the backend generates for the Rust code you wrote. This is apparently not the case, at least when unsafe is involved, which is super interesting.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman As a follow-up to your answer: AFAICS there is nothing that prevents library code implementing their own `MyRef`, and doing it wrong. Where in the usage of `UnsafeCell` would `MyRef` fail to adhere to the contract? Also:  Inside `foo`, `data` can't be mutated through either `reference` nor `data` before `drop(reference)`. So while both `MyRef` and `data` would be `noalias`, UB can't actually manifest, can it?

Comment: @user2722968 If you will follow the discussion about `Ref`, you will see that there was talk about language changes. I'm not sure what (and if) documented behavior this code breaks, but it's certainly non-intuitive (and thus people wanted to change it). About the Rust AM UB, I'm not sure if there is any. There could not, like you say (and this will be only LLVM UB), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

As I found this very interesting, here's a bit more in-depth answer to complement the one by @Chayim Friedman:

The [LLVM Language Reference](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#parameter-attributes) defines the `noalias` parameter attribute as follows:

> [...] indicates that memory locations accessed via pointer values based on the argument or return value are not also accessed, during the execution of the function, via pointer values not based on the argument or return value. [...]

This leads to the problem: If a `Ref` passed in as a *function parameter* got this attribute, it would be a lie. Once the `Ref` is dropped, it's possible to get a mutable reference to the same memory location by calling `borrow_mut` on the original `RefCell`.

Note that this is a *parameter* attribute. It is only placed on *function parameters*, not arbitrary variables. That's why the example from the question
is not problematic, and it's in general not possible to cause this issue in safe Rust.

---

If we look at the LLVM IR [generated for this example](https://godbolt.org/z/v7WxvKfEG) (in release mode):

```rust
use std::cell::{Cell, RefCell, Ref};
pub struct Ref2<'b, T: ?Sized + 'b> {
    value: &'b T,
    borrow_flag: &'b Cell<isize>,
}

pub fn foo<'a>(myref: Ref<'a, i32>, mydata: &'a RefCell<i32>) {
    drop(myref);    
    *mydata.borrow_mut() = 0;
}

pub fn foo2<'a>(myref: Ref2<'a, i32>, mydata: &'a RefCell<i32>) {
    drop(myref);    
    *mydata.borrow_mut() = 0;
}
```

We can see the difference:

```
define void @example::foo(
    ptr nocapture noundef nonnull readnone %myref.0,
    ptr nocapture noundef nonnull align 8 %myref.1,
    ptr nocapture noundef nonnull align 8 %mydata
) 
define void @example::foo2(
    ptr noalias nocapture noundef readonly align 4 dereferenceable(4) %myref.0,
    ptr nocapture noundef nonnull readnone align 8 %myref.1,
    ptr nocapture noundef nonnull align 8 %mydata
)
```

Only in `foo2` does the `%myref.0` ptr (our `value`) contain a `noalias` function parameter attribute.