# Does this code violate the unique mutable reference principle?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = String::from("hello,");
    let r = &mut v;

    println!("{}", r); // hello,

    match *r {
        ref mut value => {
            value.push_str(" world"); 
            //r could also be used here, which makes the block different from a function
        },
    }

    println!("{}", r); // hello, world  (but not changed via r)
}
```

The mutable references `value` lives within the scope of the other mutable references `r`. It seems the match expression somehow masks the existence of `r` out temporarily but hey, from `r`'s perspective there is indeed another mutable reference to its underlying value and changes them while `r` is still in use.

Comment: [No need to involve `match`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6eeb7106febfae37cf7a40eaf3618556), and note that you can only use `r` after you stop using `value` ([non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes)).

Comment: @Ry You can replace that match block to ```let value = &mut v``` or  ```let value = r``` the compiler both complains. But you are right it's not about ```match``` but ```*r```.

Comment: `let value = &mut v;` borrows `v` a second time, `let value = r;` *moves* `r` (`&mut T` is *not* `Copy`). What you're doing is reborrowing (it's borrowing from `r`, not `v`), which is fine.