# Why does Rust compiler allow 2 mutable references at the same time?

Tags: rust

In rust compiler does not allow to have more than one mutable borrow at the same time (in the same scope). Or does it?

Consider following code:

```
let mut s = String::from("Hello, world!");
let s1 = &mut s;
let s2 = &mut s;
mutate(s2);

fn mutate(s: &mut String) {
    s.push_str("!!!");
}
```

This code compiles and works, even if there are 2 mutable references.

I thought that maybe the `s1` one is not actually created, as compiler can detect that it is not used anywhere. However it is not the case because if `s1` is passed to `mutate` instead of `s2`, the code does not compile, complaining that `s1` cannot be used because second mutable reference was created.

What are really scopes of those references? Why the first version of code works?

Comment: There are no two mutable references _at the same time_.

Comment: In other words, `s1` is dropped before `s2` is created.

Comment: these question+answer might help understand: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/11527076